# how can we edit chart data in excel worksheet from a ppt generated by tbs?

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

We have one empty chart and we are loading via tbs and plotting the graph, everything works fine

when we open the newly created ppt and try to edit chart data in excel (**Edit data in excel**) it's empty, we don't see any coordinate available.

is this a limitation with this lib?

https://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc

Answer (score 1):

Editing the Chart data using an Ms Excel worksheet is a feature provided only by Ms Office and it uses a cached Excel worksheet. AS soon as the Chart template data are merged with new data by OpenTBS, the library has to delete the cached Excel worksheet because it becomes inconsistent with the new data, and it would be too much complicated to rebuild or update it.

Nevertheless, the new data corresponding to chart can be reached using the *Select data* dialog box. The data is given as a formatted string.

This limitation will be precised in the documentation soon.